# Mongo Db starting error(everytime)

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

I am not able to start mongo db. 
It gives the same error everytime.

```
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=80283 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ubuntu
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.6
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: c55eb86ef46ee7aede3b1e2a5d184a7df4bfb5b5
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-07-19T07:39:16.964-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-07-19T07:39:16.965-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-07-19T07:39:16.965-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Or sometimes port in use error.

```
fogserver@iotlab-FogServer:~$ mongod
2017-07-19T17:24:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=21462 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=iotlab-FogServer
2017-07-19T17:24:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.6
2017-07-19T17:24:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: c55eb86ef46ee7aede3b1e2a5d184a7df4bfb5b5
2017-07-19T17:24:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-07-19T17:24:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-07-19T17:24:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-07-19T17:24:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-07-19T17:24:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-07-19T17:24:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-07-19T17:24:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-07-19T17:24:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-07-19T17:24:01.317+0200 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2017-07-19T17:24:01.317+0200 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2017-07-19T17:24:01.317+0200 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2017-07-19T17:24:01.317+0200 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: InternalError: Failed to set up sockets
2017-07-19T17:24:01.317+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-07-19T17:24:01.317+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-07-19T17:24:01.317+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-07-19T17:24:01.317+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
fogserver@iotlab-FogServer:~$
```

Then I have to restart the service everytime. Please suggest how this can be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because a MongoDB server is already running on your system, likely as a daemonized service.

According to your tags, you're running Ubuntu 16.04, which uses `systemd`. You can check the running state of the service using this command:

```
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

If this reports as running, you already have a MongoDB server running - try to connect to it normally without manually starting `mongod`.

If you don't want/need a daemonized service to start at system boot, you can disable MongoDB from running with this:

```
sudo systemctl disable mongodb
sudo systemctl stop mongodb
```

Now, you can start and manually stop MongoDB using either `mongod` or by starting/stopping the daemon:

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

I would personally ***highly*** recommend you continue to use your daemonized service, as you don't need to worry about it failing or similar. If security is a concern, block MongoDB's ports in your firewall.

---

If you need log entries for a running daemonized service, you can use the `journalctl` command, like so:

```
sudo journalctl -u mongodb
```

If you want a live journal, add the `-f` command-line flag to the `journalctl` command.

---

If, for some reason, you need *both* a daemonized MongoDB and a launch-on-demand MongoDB, you will need to change the bind information and data directory for one of the two instances. See [here](https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-change-mongodb-default-listening-port-27017-92e35f65670e) for part of the puzzle.

Alternatively, you can just stop the service while running the daemon directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed the steps and got mongodb active but still not able to run it.
database@ubuntu:~$ mongod
MongoDB starting : pid=7058 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ubuntu
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.6
 NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2017-07-19T18:33:23.984-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: InternalError: Failed to set up sockets

Comment: @DivyaNair What's your service status? According to that error, MongoDB is currently running.

Comment: Yes, it is running but not starting when i type mongod or sudo mongod

Comment: If it's running, you don't need to run `mongod` again. That's the server command. If you want a CLI, use just `mongo`.